# PHP POST Request Receiving Null Variables

Tags: php, api, post, endpoint

I am new to PHP.

I have a code that creates a simple POST Request to send name and email as follows:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
} 

$name = ($_POST['name']);
$email = ($_POST['email']);
```

name and email are always empty.

This script is hosted on a subdomain https://developer.xyz.com/api-v1/insertsubscriber/ (with SSL) and the xyz.com domain also has an SSL. And no redirection exists.

The request is called from postman as:

```
POST /api-v1/insertsubscriber/ HTTP/1.1
Host: developer.xyz.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 45

{"name":"myname",
"email":"myemail@meme.com"}
```

And also tried to disable CORS:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: token, Content-Type');
```

What might be causing the problem?

Comment: please show the code that creates the POST request - be that a form or javascript or whatever.

Comment: from where name & email is coming?

Comment: Quesiton updated

Comment: It appears that you are sending JSON data that happens to have both `name` and `email` as parameters within the JSON string rather than as separate fields in the POST array

Comment: @CBroe Thanks this solved it for me. Could you please explain?